# Only internally re-directing old website to new website within the new website's .htacess file only. How do I do this?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

Old website: luffyforums.com/

New website: captainluffy.net/

Lets say I don't have access to my old website. Hence, I can't change the htaccess file from my old website.

I want all links within my new website, which lead to old website to automatically get re-direct to my new website.

It's a vbulletin website.

Example:

A user has posted the following link:

1) http://luffyforums.com/showgroups.php

2) luffyforums.com/faq.php

I want it to be changed to:

1) http://www.captainluffy.net/showgroups.php

2) captainluffy.net/faq.php

if anybody clicks it.

Basically, I'm looking for a coding which makes the new website re-direct all links associated with "luffyforums.com" to "captainluffy.net" without having to access the old domain server. 
Preferably a coding which I only have to add to my new website's .htaccess file.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You're screwed. When someone goes to `http://luffyforums.com/` the browser sends a request right to `luffyforums.com`, and it isn't even aware that such a place called `www.captainluffy.net` even exists. The request will be handled by your old website and that's it.

Since your new website (htaccess, the server, the code, everything) isn't even remotely part of this equation, you can't do any redirect *from* your old website unless you have control over it.

If you were able to do such a thing, people would be redirecting links from banks or ebay or paypal to their private phishing sites to scam people.

Comment: You've misunderstood. Your last paragraph clearly demonstrates this. It's a forum (vbulletin). Members have left links to the old site on it. I just want all links with the phrase "luffyforum.com" to get re-directed to "captainluffy.com" within "captainluffy.com". It's my website, therefore I just want all links left on it, to NOT go to my old website.

Comment: @mark the htaccess file can't change content. When you have content that has links that point to the old site, and someone clicks on it, the browser's going to the old site. Nothing in that scenario interacts with the htaccess file on your new site. If you need to edit your content, do a global replace in your database to change all the links. The worst case is using something like [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) to dynamically filter **all** outgoing content, slow and incredibly ineffecient way to do this

Comment: "Nothing in that scenario interacts with the htaccess file on your new site" Ah okay. "If you need to edit your content, do a global replace in your database to change all the links." -> I'll try and figure out a way to do that then.

Comment: @mark if you are using something like mysql, look up the REPLACE command to globally replace text